# Change a dictionary value whilst iterating over it

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

So I have the following code which iterates over a list and uses the data to populate a dict.

```
self.data = [["name1.co.uk", "123", "A", "1.2.3.4"],["name2.com", "122", "NS", "ns1.google.com"]]

for each_list in self.data:
            self.terrarecord[each_list[0].replace('.', '')] = {
                "zone_id": self.zone_id,
                "name": each_list[0] + self.url, # not sure if I need to do this
                "type": each_list[2],
                "ttl": each_list[1],
                "records": [each_list[3].replace('\n', '')]
            }
```

**I realise this probably isn't very Pythonic, so any suggestions on how to do this more eloquently would be appreciated**

Anyhoo, what I want to do is add a random value to each key generated as the code loops through the data.

So where it says `self.terrarecord[each_list[0].replace('.', '')] = {` I want to add a randomly generated number on the end, so the finished result might look something like this:

```
"key123" { # <-- This is the key that needs a random number
    "id": "id",
    "name": "key.co.uk",
    "type": "SOA",
    "records": ["1234 etc"]

}
```

As you can see in the loop it is using the same data in the `data` list to populate more than one key, and the first one needs to be unique hence why I want to add the integer as I loop through.

I hope this makes sense. It's quite difficult to explain.

Thanks

Comment: what's in `self.data`? what is the make up of `each_list`?

Comment: Sorry, an example is now added.

Comment: One improvement might be to change the 'internal' lists in self.data to instead be `namedtuple`s. Or even promote them to a full class, and then implement some of the logic in methods of that class.

Comment: Instead of trying to do it all on one line, construct the key on one line and use it in the next.  The [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module should have something you could use to construct the key.

Comment: There are numerous ways to accomplish this. Try constructing the key with something from the random module.  If you run into problems, post another question.   ```key = each_list[0].replace('.', '') + str(random.random())```

Comment: @MaxWeaver Sorry, I removed it because of a mistake I made. I wanted to correct the mistake before making the answer visible again. It is back now :)

Comment: Your title does not reflect the question you are asking - ```I want to do is add a random value to each key generated as the code loops through the data.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
import random

...
rand_key = random.randint(1, 100)

self.terrarecord[each_list[0].replace('.', '') + str(rand_key)] = {
...
}
```

You can adjust the range you want the random number to be chosen from with the arguments to `randint()`. Not that this will make it difficult to access the values from this `dict` however.

Also, there is a potential with this method for having data overwritten if `each_list[0].replace('.', '')` and `rand_key` happen to have the same value as a previous key. If this is not an issue, then this method should work for you. If it is, you could generate your "random" number with a timestamp:

```
from datetime import datetime

rand_key = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%s%f')
```

Which should give you a unique key unless the same value for `each_list[0].replace('.', '')` comes up twice in the same microsecond. See http://strftime.org/ for an explanation of the format codes passed to `strftime()`.

Answer (score 0):

So you probably want to use `randint` to get a random value but you also want to make sure that the random number isn't used before if `each_list[0]` can be the same (if they aren't idk why you need a random value appended).

```
from random import randint

data = [["name1.co.uk", "123", "A", "1.2.3.4"],["name2.com", "122", "NS", "ns1.google.com"]]
terrarecord={}

def getRandKey(name,record,key_length=3):
  min=int('1'+'0'*(key_length-1))
  max=int('9'*key_length)
  r=randint(min,max)
  new_name=name+str(r)
  while new_name in record:
    r=randint(min,max)
    new_name=name+str(r)
  return new_name

for each_list in data:
    terrarecord[getRandKey(each_list[0].replace('.', ''),terrarecord)] = {
                "zone_id": 5,
                "name": each_list[0], 
                "type": each_list[2],
                "ttl": each_list[1],
                "records": [each_list[3].replace('\n', '')]
    }
```

Comment: Or you could create a random list  - ```n_s = random.sample(list(range(len(data)*5)), len(data))``` then use ```for i, each_list in enumerate(data)``` when iterating and use the enumeration to index the list - ```key = each_list[0].replace('.', '') + str(n_s[i])```